# Makefiles: how to get a file name for a rule target from outside, in a portable way

Tags: shell, makefile

I need to get some external data to form an output file name in a Makefile.

In *GNU Make* I can do something like this :

```
NAME=$(shell some_commands)
$(NAME).out: file.in
     compile "$<" -o "$@"
```

Some other rules have `$(NAME).out` as a prerequisite so I need `$(NAME).out` as a target. I can't use substitution+quotes here as this is not interpreted by a shell.

I see from the *BSD Make* man page that on Mac OS X I should be able to do something like this (I could not test it yet, though) :

```
NAME!=some_commands
$(NAME).out: file.in
     compile "$<" -o "$@"
```

Is there a hack to do this kind of things in a portable way?

I do not want to generate the Makefile and clutter the build process. I though of includes, but they also have a different syntax across Make versions.

Comment: It's a good questions, but I don't think I've ever seen it done. Simply insisting on GNU make is very common.

Comment: On OS X 10.6.2: `make --version` returns `GNU Make 3.81` and `built for i386-apple-darwin10.0`.

Comment: Oh, I remember having had BSD Make on Tiger by default. But I think I'll still keep it portable if possible, having a workaround similar to Pavel's method 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can propose several tricks.  All them are based on the outsourcing the execution of `some_commands` to a rule body, and ensuring that their result will be utilized properly.

1. That's my favourite.  Include a makefile, which you create on your own, that contains the rule for `$(NAME)`.  At the beginning of processing it will be re-created and the proper target will appear.  The thing is that the process of creation of this makefile is done within shell commands:

   ```
   include aux_makefile
   .PHONY aux_makefile
   aux_makefile:
       NAME=`some_commands` ; ( \
           echo $$NAME.out: file.in ; \
           echo "\t rm aux_makefile" ; \
           echo "\t compile ..."  ) >$@
   ```
2. A variation of first one: make a wrapper makefile that first writes the auxilliary makefile and then recursively calls the original makefile, the auxilliary makefile being included into it.  No special build target needed.
3. Make a dummy target with a static name; it will represent `$(NAME).out`.  I.e.:

   ```
   all: dummy    # Instead of all: $(NAME).out
   dummy: file.in
      NAME=`some_commands`; compile "$<" -o "$$NAME"
      touch $@
   ```

Comment: Eventually I just did a variation of method 3 (I want it to be the simplest possible and easy modifiable by others !!). I simply made a static rule on which other rules depend, and a copy with the appropriate name as an user output.

Comment: @Piotr, that would work too, but the key thing here is that this rule should not be `.PHONY`, and it should `touch` the file equal to its name, so that it avoids unnecessary recompilation.

Comment: yeah, exactly, I have a non-`.PHONY` rule, and so a static output file name for the build process, and then another file name with the required name. So not totally pretty, but avoids recompilation, and all files have significant content.

But I once also rediscovered the hack with `touch` trying to do the minimal amount of LaTeX recompilations :)

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of clumsy, and I don't know enough about different versions of Make to know if it's really portable, but it might work, and it satisfies your strict conditions (no generating the makefile, no 'include', and things can depend on $(NAME).out). If there is only one target you intend to make from the command line (say, 'all') then you can write it like this:

```
ifeq ($(origin NAME), undefined)
all:
    @$(MAKE) -s all NAME=some_commands_using_substituion_and_quotes
else
all: some_preqs_maybe_including_NAME
    do_other_things
endif
```

When you run Make, NAME is undefined, so the rule runs Make again with NAME defined-- since the command IS interpreted by the shell. (The "@" and "-s" are just to make it quieter.) And if you try to make other targets "by hand" you'll have a lot of trouble since $(NAME) will evaluate to nothing.

Comment: Oh, that's also clever, but I'm not quite sure it's portable, from what I see on the BSD Make Manual, directives have a different syntax (`.if` ...).

Comment: As usual, better than mine :-)

Comment: @Pavel, oh stop it. You gave three solutions, I gave one that puts a serious limitation on the use of the makefile and probably isn't even portable (which was the whole point). Say, maybe we could write a makefile that detects which version is running it, then defines an IFTHEN function... Or maybe we could just write a virus to destroy all non-GNU makefiles, it would be less horrible.

Comment: Your method is completely non-portable. The only way to implement something like if-then-else in make is to use pattern macro expansions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a portable way to do this if you do not try to use the non-portable BSD extension.

A working makefile would look this way:

```
NAME = $(shell some command) # This is the non-portable gmake syntax
NAME :sh= some command       # This is mostly portable from SunPro Make
NAME != some command        # Also possible (POSIX style)

all:
    echo $(NAME)
```

The second method was introduced in 1986 by `SunPro Make` and is supported by `smake` and `BSD make` as well.

If you like to verify this, `SunPro Make` and `smake` are part of the schilytools.